# SonarQube - PHP - Review the data-flow - use of uninitialized value

Tags: php, foreach, sonarqube

I have this code which works perfectly fine:

`if ($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) :
        doSomething($key, $value)
    endforeach
}`

But when deployed, SonarQube gives me this "bug":

**Review the data-flow - use of uninitialized value.**

with `$key` underlined.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does it also do the same when you use braces for the ForEach? `foreach () { ... }`

Comment: Your code doesn't parse and I can't reproduce the issue. Which version of SonarPHP do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As awkward as it seems to be, I fixed it by adding

```
$key = null
```

before foreach loop!